# How to convert Universal Windows App to Class Library Project?

Tags: uwp

I know how to convert Windows Desktop Application to class library, since it has output type under Application Tab in Project properties. But there is no such thing in uwp apps. Any idea of how to covert Universal Windows App to Class Library Project?

Comment: If not automatic, I guess do it manually?

Comment: Creating a class library project and moving each folder and classes, adding references seems tedious. If there is a way like editing the property file, removing app.xaml etc.., it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way for you to do this but some more settings need to be modified by yourself. 
You can try right click your project and then choose to unload it. After that edit your csproject and change the following:

```
<OutputType>winmdobj</OutputType>
```

At this time, if you right click your project to see the properties, you can see the output type is now DLL and Windows Runtime Component.

For more settings, I recommend that you can unload a windows runtime component and a common app project and then compare their .csproj file.

Comment: Thanks. It works. In my case, I used <OutputType>Library</OutputType> and removed AppxManifest and few unnecessary lines as you mentioned. Thanks a lot.